# "in a given factors" or "The decision will vary in given factors"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I would like to ask about these words. Which one is grammatically correct?

> "The decision will vary in a given factors"

or

> "The decision will vary in given factors" ?

Since the word "factors" refers to more than one thing, I think it should be plural. I have searched in google, but the result shows both of them exist.

Comment: In English, /to vary in a factor is not idiomatic/. By that, do you mean: Various factors will vary in arriving at a decision? Or something else. Kindly explain. Thanks.

Comment: I commented on this yesterday and my comment seems to have disappeared....:)

Answer (score 1):

> given factors

is surely plural, so the second example is correct. One example I find is

> a given factors-levels setting

here we are referring to the setting, which is singular.

The overall sentence doesn't seem quite right to me. I would not say that decisions vary **in** something, rather

> The decision will depend upon the given factors.

This assumes that earlier in the text we have stated (given) the factors that help us make the decision.

Answer (score 1):

Since "factors" is plural, then the adjective "a" in the first sentence is incorrect.

The second sentence is better, but still very awkward. I think you're trying to say:

> *Depending on the given factors, the decision may change.*

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to describe *variance*.  The first is to say some thing has many different *variations*, in which case "vary in" is appropriate:

> Apples **vary in** size, color, taste, and texture.

In this case it sounds more like you want to say the variance *depends* on some other factors.  Here "vary with" is appropriate:

> The size of the stadium crowds **varies with** the weather.

Singular or plural doesn't really matter:

> What people eat **varies with** the available options.

Also, it is correct to use the definite article "the" before the factors, if you've already described them.

> The decision will vary with **the** given factors.

**However** all that being said, the more "natural" way to say this would be:

> The decision **depends on the various given factors**.